# Optimizing Foundation5 Workflow

Tags: gruntjs, workflow, compass-sass, zurb-foundation-5, libsass

I have a basic question about Foundation5 setup, and associated publishing workflow. I'm on a learning curve towards creating a better local dev-to-publish workflow, so bear with me please...

Currently, I create F5 Compass projects; straightforward, but lacks programatic minification, concatenation, (CSS) cleaning, etc. LibSass projects, and a process like [this](https://corydowdy.com/blog/foundation-5-sass-and-grunt-uncss), seem to readily offer these capabilities.

My question, essentially, if this is correct, and if not, how such capabilities can be added to a Compass project? I ask this simply because I have existing Compass projects under development that could use the aforementioned utilities and, also as mentioned, I want to build a better approach in general.

Conceivably, I could migrate existing Compass projects (local instances of ModX) to LibSass, but I'm sure this would come with complications.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: you can automate these tasks using task runners.. grunt or gulp, how can that be added to a compass project is not easy to answer with out knowing your project setup.

Comment: What additional details about about the setup would be helpful?